# Expected size of a largest convex subset of given points in general position?

Tags: probability, geometry

Suppose that $n$ points are in general position with different $y$ coordinates.  [Erdös-Szekeres conjecture](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/erdos_szekeres_conjecture%20conjecture) states that

> Every set of $2^{n-2} + 1$ points in the plane in general position
>   contains a subset of $n$ points which form a convex $n$-gon.

Also, there is a result on [expected complexity of a convex hull](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.5340) which is $O(n^{1/3})$.

However, I could not find any results/conjectures on the expected size of the largest convex subset of points in 2D.

Is there any research considers this problem?